# How Can I Center One <li> in a <ul>

Tags: css

I have a top menu made by a list. All `<li>`s centers depending on the text though I want to center one the `<li>`s and then the rest of the `<li>`s should center on both sides. I want to center the image.

The top menu looks like this:

```
<div id="topMenu">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="index.php">Forside</a></li>
      <li><a href="matches.php">Kampe</a></li>
      <li><a href="squad.php">Truppen</a></li>
      <li><a href="index.php"><img id="logoMenu" src="images/logo.png"></a></li>  
      <li><a href="#">Galleri</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Statistik</a></li>
      <li><a href="about.php">Om Klubben</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Then I have some CSS:

```
#topMenu {
    background: #51a047;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    line-height: 25px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#topMenu ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: center;
}

#topMenu li {
    display: inline;
    padding: 0 20px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

#logoMenu {
    background-image: url("images/logo.png");
    width: 80px;
}

#topMenu img {
    vertical-align: text-top;
}
```

Here's a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vvu5k79r/1/)

Comment: Thereis no simple CSS setting that will let you do this. You would need to restructure the HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally I wouldn't have the logo as an element in the navigation. Semantically it doesn't make sense and its difficult to style. If you divide the menu items in to two ULs you can do the following:

**HTML**

```
<div id="topMenu">
    <ul id="menu-left">
        <li><a href="#">AAA</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">BBB</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">CCC</a></li>
    </ul>
    <a href="#" id="logoMenu"><img src="URL" /></a>
    <ul id="menu-right">
        <li><a href="#">DDD</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">EEE</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">FFF</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#topMenu {
    background: #51a047;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    line-height: 25px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
}

#topMenu ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    text-align: center;

    margin: 0;
    padding: 10px;

    box-sizing: border-box; /* percentage width + padding */
    width: 45%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
}

#topMenu #menu-left {
    left: 0;
}
#topMenu #menu-right {
    right: 0;
}

#topMenu li {
    display: inline;
    padding: 0 20px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

#topMenu a {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#logoMenu {
    display: block;
    width: 10%;
    margin: 0 auto; /*center*/
}

#topMenu img {
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: block;
    max-height: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/vvu5k79r/2/